# Hibernate SQLQuery bypasses hibernate session cache

Tags: hibernate, jboss, transactional

I'm "transactionalizing" some extensive database manipulation and I came across this issue where if I run sql queries through hibernate but not using the MQL approach, the view of the database doesn't appear correct. Specifically the code uses the hibernate in the more appropriate manner in most cases but there are places where someone decided to just execute sql. I don't like that they did this but at this point "it is what it is".

I found an [explanation](http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/Hibernate/SQL+vs+HQL+with+the+Session+Cache) that seems to explain it but all the examples are wrt actually getting and managing the transaction in the code. We are using the @TransactionAttribute annotation on the entire class to change this code and are finding a lot of places where this behavior happens but I'm not entirely convinced the explanation applies to code that is simply wrapped in the annotation--I was assuming that anything using the hibernate manager would rely on the object cache in the session.

Apologies in advance if I am referring to concepts in hibernate by incorrect terminology, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is confusing, but I assume you are saying that Hibernate is not looking for entities in the Session cache when you are performing Native queries.

SQL Query, or Native Query, is a query which Hibernate just relays to the database. Hibernate won't parse the query, and it won't parse the results. Hibernate will, though, let you handle the results, to convert the columns into properties of a class. That said, it sounds quite natural that Native Queries would bypass the Session cache. That's because Hibernate doesn't knows anything about your query, nor about the "results" of this query (which are not objects at that point).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. thanks. I'm assuming, moving forward that using the the annotation has the same behavior as if you were to manually get the txn from session and manipulate it in the code.

Comment: oh, and apologies for the confusing wording. That's a solid reflection of how far into hibernate I actually am :) New job--just started day 12 :P

Answer (score 9):

Actually the "explanation" blog by Chris Landry misses 3 important API methods of SQLQuery and thats in fact why he has those problems.  Specifically, (1) addSynchronizedQuerySpace, (2) addSynchronizedEntityName and (3) addSynchronizedEntityClass

As partenon points out, just based on the SQL query string itself Hibernate has no way to know what tables and/or entities are queried in the query.  Therefore, it has no idea what changes queued up in the Session need to be flushed to the database.  In the blog Chris does point out that you can perform a flush() call on your own prior to running the SQL query.  However, what I am describing is Hibernate's auto-flush capability.  It actually does the same thing for HQL and Criteria queries.  Only there it *knows* the tables being affected.  Anyway, this process of auto-flushing does a "minimal flush" flushing only things that affect the query.  Thats where these methods come into play.

As an example, Chirs's SQL query is

```
session.createSqlQuery("select name from user where name = :userName")
```

Really all he needed to do was to say...

```
session.createSqlQuery("select name from user where name = :userName")
        .addSynchronizedQuerySpace( "user" )
```

The `addSynchronizedQuerySpace( "user" )` is telling Hibernate that the query uses a table named "user".  Now Hibernate can auto flush all changes pending for entities mapped to that user table.

Comment: but under heavy load this leads to very frequence flushes which leads to absence of caching at all.

Comment: Sorry but choosing performance *over* correctness is just asking for problems.  You get something working correctly first and then you work on making it perform better.  Furthermore, the caching that gets invalidated on this type of flushing is the second level cache.  Enabling second level caching on data that is not a good candidate can quite often lead to even worse performance.  Sounds like that is the situation you find yourself in.

Comment: Just to clarify, does the original question and this answer apply to the first-level cache? We have the second-level cache turned off, but are using native SQL queries, and I'm trying to understand the risks.

Comment: @MichaelEaster I think the answer refers to the 2nd level cache, as for the 1st level cache the solution would be to make a session.flush() before the query. However if the native query is done in another session (not the one where the entity is cached), then I don't know what the solution could be.