# Does SQLQuery in Hibernate use the session cache?

Tags: hibernate, caching

[This blog post](http://i-proving.com/2006/08/29/sql-vs-hql-with-the-session-cache/) (referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500221/hibernate-sqlquery-bypasses-hibernate-session-cache)) says that SQLQuery does not use the Hibernate session cache.  However, a) there's no evidence, b) they don't use SQLQuery.addEntity, which might give information allowing Hibernate to use its cache.

[The docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17428) don't mention caching one way or another.

Does SQLQuery use the session cache if I use addEntity?

**Edit**: [This section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-sessioncache) of the docs says:

> Whenever you pass an object to save(), update() or saveOrUpdate(), and
>   whenever you retrieve an object using load(), get(), list(), iterate()
>   or scroll(), that object is added to the internal cache of the
>   Session.

Since addEntity() allows list() to return objects, that implies it is using the cache. How can I check?  Those same docs say there is a "contains" method for the cache, and one can browse the second-level cache, but not how to browse the session cache.

**Edit #2**: By turning on logging of Hibernate queries, it does not seem to be caching, but perhaps some set of circumstances would make it cache.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think beny23's answer is correct. I believe `setCacheable` refers to second level caching not session cache.

To check if an entity is in the session cache you can use `Session.contains()`.  You could also do a quick test: fetch entity, modify it, close session and see if the mod is in the db.

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadocs for [SQLQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html), it extends the `Query` interface, which provides the [setCacheable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setCacheable%28boolean%29) method (false by default), so you should be able to do the following:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
  "select * from my_table e")
  .addEntity(MyEntityClass.class)
  .setCacheable(true);
```

Additionally, you may want to look into setting the cache region by using the 
[setCacheMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/AbstractQueryImpl.html#setCacheMode%28org.hibernate.CacheMode%29) and [setCacheRegion](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/AbstractQueryImpl.html#setCacheRegion%28java.lang.String%29) methods.